# Unresolved Instance Declaration

Tags: haskell

I have two functions , one to get the squareRoot of a number which differs from the previous item by `< 0.0001` , **approx is fine**.

```
squareRoot n = squareRoot' (approx n)

squareRoot' ( n : n2 : ns ) | abs (n2 - n) < 0.0001 = n2
                            | otherwise = squareRoot' ( n2 : ns )
```

And another which uses it to list the infinite list of primes

```
primes = [ n | n <- [ 2 .. ], isPrime n ]

isPrime 2 = True
isPrime 3 = True

isPrime n = isPrime' n (squareRoot n) primes

isPrime' n squareRoot (h : t)   
   | h < squareRoot && mod n ( h :: Int ) /= 0 = False
   | otherwise = isPrime' n squareRoot t
```

I simple cannot see the instance declaration that I must make that results in

```
No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `squareRoot'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int)
In the second argument of isPrime', namely `(squareRoot n)'
In the expression: isPrime' n (squareRoot n) primes
In an equation for `isPrime':
    isPrime n = isPrime' n (squareRoot n) primes
```

Could someone help me out ? Thanks

Comment: I think you might solve the error with using `fromIntegral (abs (n2-n))`.

Comment: You should add type annotations to your functions. In that way you'll see that `squareRoot` produces some type in the `Rational` typeclass, while later on you expect an `Int`. If you want to keep it simple, make `squareRoot` return a `Double`, and use `fromIntegral` and `floor` to convert ints to doubles and back, as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aside from the things already mentioned in the comments I think that you want to use your `squareRoot` to got only to `sqrt p` while checking for divisors for your `isPrime` predicate right?

if so, then instead of using conversion and `sqrt` and stuff you can just make use of

```
m <= sqrt n <=> m^2 <= n
```

like this:

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime 1 = False
isPrime p = null [ d | d <- takeWhile (\ m -> m^2 <= p) [2..], p `mod` d == 0 ]
```

and get:

```
λ> take 20 primes
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71]
```

as well ;)

---

in case you are looking for a way to get `floor (sqrt p)` for (I assume `approx` is some kind of algorithm to get you a series of numbers to calculate roots), than using the same observation this would just be

```
sqrtn :: Integer -> Integer
sqrtn n = head [ m | m <- [n,n-1..1], m^2 <= n ]
```